# Pentaho PDI : Excel Input ignore all columns after an empty column. How to full import?

Tags: excel, pentaho, pdi

With empty column or empty header in Excel file : Excel imput ignore all columns after...... it's a problem.

=> How to solve ?

=> Is there a way to specify column manually by number/letter ?

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We find a solution.

You can put a `null` value and continue to fill manually headers grid, like this :

[image]